# Como obter o id do botão clicado em uma linha de listagem de resultados pelo Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como obter o id do botão clicado em uma linha de listagem de resultados pelo Angular JS?

No página HTML posso usar o list.id, porém no código em AngularJS, os códigos abaixo me retornam **undefined**:

```
id;

$scope.id;

$scope.listagensRelatorios.id;

$scope.parametro.id;

$routeParams.id 


    app.controller("listagemRelatoriosController", function($scope, $http, $location, $q) {

    $scope.listagensRelatorios = [];
    $scope.listagemRelatorio = {};

    carregarListagemRelatorios = function() {

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/listagemRelatorios',

        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.listagensRelatorios = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });

    };


    gerarRelatorioSelecionado = function() {

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/listagemRelatorios' + $scope.listagensRelatorios.id,

        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.listagensRelatorios = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });

    };



    carregarListagemRelatorios();
    gerarRelatorioSelecionado();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o id na chamada da função no html.

HTML:

```
 <div ng-click="getId(list.id)">List item</div>
```

Função:

```
 $scope.getId = function(param) {
   console.log(param);
   //insira o código aqui
 }
```

Espero ter ajudado.